# Rational Application Developer 9.1.1, unable to add runtime Websphere Portal runtime

Tags: websphere-portal, ibm-rad

I am unable to add Websphere Portal 8.5 CF07 installation as a runtime in Rational Application developer 9.1.1 client.

Selecting my 8.5 installation without any fixpacks works as expected.

For 8.5CF07 the runtime dialog gives no errors, but the finish button stays grayed out.

Both installations 8.5 and 8.5CF07 are installed on my local machine on the same drive.

Any idea how to solve or debug this issue? Do I need another server adapter? If so, where can I download newer adapters? I have checked the Eclipse Market place and several IBM Repositories.

I am using Windows 10 as OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reinstall of the portal server, with the default was profile folder name: "wp_profile", solved the issue. In previous installs we used "WPProfile" as folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the Portal server adapters when installing RAD? did you installed RAD via Installation Manager? if so, launch IM and modify your installation to include the Portal adapters.

[image]

Comment: I have used IM to install RAD, but the adapters are selected already. I have not selected the remote server stubs, but this should not be mandatory I assume? [Adapters screenshot](http://imgur.com/nr9GL4p)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the location of your Portal 8.5 CF07 directories (PortalServer and AppServer)?

Typically (you probably already know this) CF is installed on top of an existing Portal installation. Make sure that while defining a new server, you provide the correct path to the PortalServer directory in the **WebSphere Portal location** field and also the correct path to the underlying WAS server in the **WebSphere Application Server location** field.

See the image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoOHC.png

Also, you can try to restart RAD with a new workspace. RAD should automatically detect the Portal Servers.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: As you can see in the screenshots, the config targets the correct folders. It does not mention errors in path, but finish button stays disabled. [Screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/tnjXA)

Comment: I also installed RAD 9.5 to see if this solves the problem, but it has the same problem. My colleagues have the same issue with version of Portal.

I am able to start the server manually and use it, so it seems it is properly installed. But my colleagues use the same portal image, so I suspect there might be something in this install or fixpack...

Comment: Yes. Your directory structure looks fine. I will check this further to see what could be the issue. Meanwhile, can you try to restart RAD with a new workspace and see if RAD detects your CF07 Portal or not?

Comment: I used Portal 85 CF07 and i am not facing any such issue. Can you point me to the location from where you have got the Portal image?

Comment: A reinstall of the portal server, with the default was profile folder name: "wp_profile", solved the issue. In previous installs we used "WPProfile" as folder name. Is this not supported?

Comment: Multiple portal profiles are supported in RAD. But it looks like during the server definition, only wp_profile is being recognized. We will look into this.